# Javascript Variable and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var datetime = date + ' ' + time;

    document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML = datetime + ' <br> Day: ' + daylist[day];
};
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="height: 26px">
      <asp:Label ID="display1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I was wondering how do I display 'display1' in HTML Label? The  is the HTML code and my objective is to input the date and time (Javascript) into the label (HTML). I have used "document.getElementById" code but I could not achieve the result that I wanted.

Comment: Since you're asking how to do this with JavaScript in the browser, show us the rendered HTML, not the server-side code that creates it. Does a server-side `ASP:Label` render an HTML `label`?

Comment: I don't do ASP.Net, but as I understand it if you want a client-side ID to use, that's the [`ClientID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_ClientID) property. The `ID` property is just a server-side ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in my computer and it's working as it should.
Anyway if you want to print there the server date and time you should use the asp.net to create a date time and print directly.
Instead if you want the client date and time you can remain on javascript but remove the label and set the id in the td directly

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="4" id="display1" style="height: 26px">
 </td>
</tr>
```